# Nodemon is not restarting using docker container

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, nodemon

I've been trying to make my server restart when I make changes to my app.js file for two days without success now. Im using docker desktop and nodemon. And trying to follow the guide given by my teacher. 
I was told to make this work i should use volume, so in the terminal i run:

`docker build --tag=jade:latest .`

`docker run -v /Users/Jake/Documents/AdvancedWeb/JadeWeb/application/src:/src -p 8080:8080 jade`

On the second row I have probably tried a hundred different syntaxes, this seems to be the one closest to working and is what makes the most sense to me. It starts the server and nodemon tells me it's waiting for changes.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:13.3.0-stretch
EXPOSE 8080
WORKDIR /application
COPY package.json package.json
RUN npm install
COPY src src
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"] 
// I have tried ALOT of variants of CMD aswell, like ["npm", "run", "start", "src/app.js"], 
// ["npm", "run", "dev"], ["node", "src/app.js"] ["nodemon", "src/app.js"]
// ["npm", "start"]
```

**package.json:**

```
    {
  "name": "application",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --legacy-watch src/app",
    "dev": "nodemon src/app -L"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.2"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: The second argument to your `-v` option is `/src`, but you declare `WORKDIR /application`; these don't line up.

Comment: (You might find it easier to run `npm run start` on the host directly, rather than a long-winded Docker command that requires root-equivalent privileges.)

Comment: I was thinking about that a bit, but I have a terrible understanding of filesystems in general. I'll try around changing those parts a bit. Thanks.

It's part of the project to use docker, but yes, just running npm run start when i'm standing in the /application directory works.

Comment: The only change I tried that still made the server start was removing the WORKDIR line, but it didn't solve the problem. As I understand it, ```-v``` is only to sync the src files when I make changes in the source code. But the working directory should include all the files. But i'm not even close to certain.

Comment: Which OS you are using?

Comment: MacOS

My answer below, about it working after a while was accaully due to removing the line ```WORKDIR /application```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Searched everywhere. Every possible solution. From attaching -L for --legacy-watch to --watch in scripts with nodemon command. My problem was in docker-compose.yml. In your app service, have a volumes attribute. Volumes basically maps the code you are writing in your system to the container environment.
So, if I write,

volumes:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              -"./application:/application"

It means that the application folder in which your nodejs app lies maps to /application in container.
Now, whatever changes you make in your system, will be reflected in the container code. Since, nodemon is already active in the node, it will restart!!

Answer (score 0):

So I forgot to close the server for a while, and apparently it does restart, but it takes about 10 seconds for the process to start, then the server is down for a few seconds, and then it restart. Also, after making a change and saving my app.js file, i get 
`[nodemon] restarting due to changes...`

7 times before it accually restarts.

If i just do `npm run start`nodemon works as intended. (A single fast restart)